# how to make a "MVC Application" with extjs 4.0 beta 3?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there someone here who made a MVC application using EXTJS 4 BETA 3? and works fine??
please help me how?, ..

I have followed step by step [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0-beta3/docs/guide/application_architecture.html) .. and @Abdel Olakara help

but there is still an error ... here my firebug

```
[Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'AM.controller.Users'; consider adding  
Ext.require('AM.controller.Users') above Ext.onReady  

[Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'AM.store.Users'; consider adding  
Ext.require('AM.store.Users') above Ext.onReady

this.getView('Viewport') is null
```

When i read [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130257-Beta3-API-Doc-Issues&p=591772&viewfull=1#post591772) at the forum ... there are still some bug with MVC guide ...

so, if you ever make it works.. how?

this is my `Application.js` :

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true}); 
Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', {
    name: 'AM',

    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ],

    views: [
        'user.List'
    ],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: {
                xtype: 'userlist'
            }
        });
    }
});
```

i'm trying to learn MVC in Extjs...
sorry if my english bad..

Comment: the MVC features are still not ready.. You will have to wait for Ext JS dev team to release it completely with all bug fixes and proper documentations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I think I should take back my words! I had some success after going through sencha blog. And finally, got my MVC "Skeleton" running!

Here is the working code:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', {
    name: 'AM',
    autoCreateViewport: false,
    controllers: [],

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    title: 'Users',
                    html : 'List of users will go here'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

**Please note that, the code is very minimal** and have removed the common errors reported in forums and here. The next step would be to start playing with this code and add controllers, views etc onto it!

I will keep updating this answer going forward.

---

**Update:** The first two error mentioned are not actually errors. They are warnings and application works fine even if they display these warnings. The third error you mentioned is a stopper!

**Solution to Viewport problem** Here are two ways to solve it.

1. Use the `autoCreateViewport: false,` property and define your viewport (I see that you have defined your viewport in launch method)
2. Create a Viewport.js and save it in view folder. In this case, I felt my launch method empty and moved the viewport code to Viewport.js file. But I do get an error:

   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of null

Comment: Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true}); is what i'm looking for...
"I had some success after going through sencha blog. And finally, got my MVC 'Skeleton' running! " which one thread?? can give me the link??

Comment: actually i still get error `this.getView("Viewport") is null`, like this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?130257-Beta3-API-Doc-Issues&p=591682&viewfull=1#post591682 ..... now i am trying so hard to fix it'

Comment: well.. no error for me.. can you post your latest code by editing the question?

Comment: all script?? or just the `Applicatition.js` ?? i think nothing different with all script here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0-beta3/docs/guide/application_architecture.html .. but just for make sure i'll edit my question with my last `Application.js`

Comment: +1 @Abdel, great... now all works for me... but the warning part is really annoying... it's like that we make an app not in Ext4-ish..

Comment: @Ebo, we will have to wait for next release from Sencha... We are few hours away from the weekly release..

Answer (score 0):

I do use ExtJS 4.1.

In my code `[Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'OOO.store.News'; consider adding

Ext.require('OOO.store.News') above Ext.onReady` warning message was invoked if I place

```
stores: [
    'News',
],
```

in my `app/Application.js` file instead of `app/controller/OOO.js` file.

So put `stores:[],` in controller file.

Comment: interesting, but it does fix the warning issue. Thanks